# How can I make my recyclerview properly display the data I am receiving from Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Getting Data from retrofit, but it will not display to the screen.

I have been learning about live data and retrofit over the last few days and I am doing my best to combine it with recyclerview, but I am messing up somewhere in my MainActivity.kt.  I have spent a few hours trying to get it myself, but I have not found the solution for my particular problem. I believe my error either lies in the lateinit portion of the code or my initRecyclerView function.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.dev20.retrofitpractice


import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.liveData
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import retrofit2.Response


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var albumsAdapter: AlbumsAdapter


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val list = ArrayList<AlbumsItem>()


        initRecyclerView()
        getData()
        albumsAdapter = AlbumsAdapter(list)
    }
        private fun getData() {
            val retService: AlbumService = RetrofitInstance
                .getRetrofitInstance()
                .create(AlbumService::class.java)
            val responseLiveData: LiveData<Response<Albums>> = liveData {
                val response = retService.getAlbums()
                emit(response)
            }

            responseLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
                val albumsList: MutableListIterator<AlbumsItem>? = it.body()?.listIterator()
                if (albumsList != null) {
                    while (albumsList.hasNext()) {
                        val albumsItem: AlbumsItem = albumsList.next()
                        Log.i("MYTAG", albumsItem.title)

                    }

                }
            })
        }

    private fun initRecyclerView() {

        recycler_view.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
            adapter = albumsAdapter
        }
    }
}
```

AlbumsAdapter.kt

```
package com.dev20.retrofitpractice

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.albums_list.view.*


class AlbumsAdapter(private val albumsList: List<AlbumsItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsAdapter.AlbumsViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AlbumsViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.albums_list,
        parent, false)

        return AlbumsViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AlbumsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = albumsList[position]

        holder.textViewAlbums.text = currentItem.title
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = albumsList.size

    class AlbumsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textViewAlbums: TextView = itemView.text_view_albums
    }
}
```

Albums.kt

```
package com.dev20.retrofitpractice

class Albums : ArrayList<AlbumsItem>()
```

AlbumsItem.kt

```
package com.dev20.retrofitpractice


import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class AlbumsItem(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String,
    @SerializedName("userId")
    val userId: Int
)
```

AlbumService.kt

```
package com.dev20.retrofitpractice

import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface AlbumService {

    //define abstract function to get albums data
    //returns retrofit response of type Albums
    //Use suspend modifier because we are using coroutines with retrofit
    @GET("/albums")
    suspend fun getAlbums() :Response<Albums>
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/albums_list"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ablums_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_albums"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: where do you initialize your adapter its not in this code?

Comment: https://medium.com/@howtodoandroid/retrofit-android-example-with-recyclerview-870e74e5b2ff This blog has a good example which might help you.

Comment: @Farid I added val albumsList = listOf<AlbumsItem>()
            albumsAdapter = AlbumsAdapter(albumsList) to my onCreate method.  I get data from the log "MYTAG", but it still will not display on the recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity oncreate add :

```
albumsAdapter = AlbumAdapter(albumList)
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get the error "Unresolved reference: albumsList" even though I can see it set as albumsList in the AlbumsAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter is not initialized. Try initializing it. And please note that passing the list via constructor is not the best approach to do it. Suppose if you have a list that is to be updated, will you initialize the adapter every time for it to be done? No! So what you should do is create a separate method for setting the list to Adapter.

**UPDATE**

You are setting an empty list to the adapter and then after that you pass the list to the adapter. So arrange your code like this:-

```
initRecyclerView()
getData()
albumsAdapter = AlbumsAdapter(list)
```

Comment: This is barely qualified as a comment .

Comment: @ADM serving it in a plate doesn't serve the purpose i believe. Its better to point someone to the issue's core rather that just writing code that solves it.

Comment: @hamzakhan I updated my MainActivity initializing the adapter and put my data response into a method I call (I am not 100% sure if this is what you meant).  I am able to see the data in logcat, but it still will not display to the screen.

Comment: @AndroidDev20TX i think after the updated code i have found a very simple mistake and that is you are setting an empty list to the adapter and after that you are adding data to the list. it doesn't work like that, you have to first pass the data to the list and then the list to the adapter. So what you need to do is this arrange your Code like this:
`getData()`
 
`albumsAdapter = AlbumsAdapter(list)`

Comment: @hamzakhan thanks for that update.  I think I am very close, but I am still not able to get a list of the data when debugging the method passed getData().  Also, when I move the line of code albumsAdater = AlbumsAdapter(list) below the getData() call, I get the error "lateinit property albumsAdapter has not been initialized" again. I've updated the code above to show the current state.

Comment: @AndroidDev20TX okay. In your getData() method, i cannot see where exactly have you added the data to the actual 'list'.
Try doing that in the observer like this :
`while (albumsList.hasNext()) {
 val albumsItem: AlbumsItem = albumsList.next()
list.add(albumsitem)
}`

Comment: And the error you get for lateinit property , is because in your initRecyclerView() method call, you are passing the adapter to the recyclerview, which is not initialized. Try calling initRecyclerview after initializing the adapter.